# Determine if UIWebView handled event

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

When user taps in UIWebView I want to show/hide navigation bar. I want to do so only if UIWebView didn't done anything in respond to this event (selected text, invoked javascript).

I've found article to determine touch coordinates:
http://mithin.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/
But there are no information if something happened inside the UIWebView.

**EDIT:** This solution **[Intercept unused tap events in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597118/intercept-unused-tap-events-in-a-uiwebview?rq=1)** is not working always in my situation, I have pretty complicated html-structure with iframes.

Comment: http://wyldco.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/   can you check this link...

Comment: I've seen this link, author shows how to intercept touches, and not how to handle if UIWebView did respond to event or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and implement methods like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

To manage whether showing navigation bar or hiding it.

Comment: These callbacks will not be invoked for all Js interactions, so they wont cover all cases here.